# OmniFaces could not convert value. Why?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, omnifaces

I'm trying to implement the OmniFaces converter omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter into a bug tracking tool that I'm working on.

It's unable to convert the object for the managed bean when clicking the form submit button

Running Netbeans 8.2, with JSF 2.2 Java EE 7, GlassFish 4.1.1. Using OmniFaces 2.7.1

JSF form input:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="priority" value = "#{createBugManagedBean.priority}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{createBugManagedBean.priorities}" var="priorities" itemValue="#{priorities}" itemLabel="#{priorities.name}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Managed bean objects:

```
private BugPrioritiesDTO priority;
private ArrayList<BugPrioritiesDTO> priorities;
```

BugPrioritiesDTO class:

```
public class BugPrioritiesDTO implements Serializable {

    Integer id;
    String name;

    public BugPrioritiesDTO(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is what gets spat out onto the webpage when clicking the form submit button.

```
Could not convert value '0' for component j_idt18:priority.
Could not convert value '0' for component j_idt18:severity.
```

Not sure what it means by value of '0'. Is it literally trying to convert an integer value of 0 to an object or does 0 denote the index of the object I'm trying to convert?

0 is the primary key representing the priority value "Lowest". If I change the priority to 'Low' it says it can't convert value '1', 'Medium' is '2'... etc.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and you know. The source is open...

Comment: I think that yout DTO must implement `equals` and `hashCode`. Omnifaces example implements them.